# how can we get the docs in users collection in firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i want to create an array from data coming from firestore.
the structure is as follows

users(collection)>uid1(doc)>(profile)>uid2(doc)>data

now the uid is dynamic as for every element of users collection. i want to create an array for every element with data
eg

```
[
{data},
{data},
.....
]
```

i have written the code for single uid

```
db.collection('users').doc("BbXn5M213XSKNfcSAR2MvbjPD403").collection("profile").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
console.log(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()));
});
```

here are some firebase screenshot
[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzsAw.png) [screenshot 2 here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xcmx.png)

Comment: We need much more info to be able to help you, e.g. error message. The link you provided does not work. Also, please add images directly in your question, not as links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you'd looking for might be a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), which is a way to get contents from all collections with a specific name.

So in your example this would be the way to get all documents from all `data` (sub)collections:

```
db.collectionGroup("profile").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
  console.log(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()));
});
```